# stop inline javascript from executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, simple-html-dom

I use simple php parser to load a page, but within the blog post there is a injected fb javascript, the DOM look like this

[image]

I tried using jQuery to remove like `$('#fb-root')` but when I think back of course it doesn't work, because jQuery run later than the like button plugin.

I do want to return header plain/text because I want to keep the style of some part.

Comment: There isn't much you'll be able to do about this with javascript, short of undoing whatever the js does after it does it.

Comment: Use the methods on whatever the parser gave you to remove any script nodes before rendering the page

Comment: If you're actually using jQuery to parse the input despite what you said in the description, you can use http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/ instead of whatever method you're using.

Comment: @mowwwalker I know but the structure of my target is terrible. Just imagine u want to content but within that there is a fb like plugin.

Comment: Have your page create an AJAX call to return the HTML content, then remove facebook content and append the rest to the page.

Comment: @user3522742, By inline, do you mean javascript that's in the onload or other attributes of an element? If you need to, just iterate over every element in the parsed DOM and remove any attribute that could contain javascript

Answer (score 0):

Well, of course you could just use some CSS:

```
#fb-root { display : none; }
```

Other than that, you could use an interval to check if "fb-root" has already been written do the document and then remove it... But I wouldn't suggest that since CSS does the job way easier.